# How to collect a value from an external ListView and use it as a condition to populate a new ListView column?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, equation

This one is a little hard to explain but I'll do my best.

I'm trying to read a Payable value (fortnightly, monthly or yearly) from my ListView, and then calculate the PremiumPayable depending on whether the Payable is 'F', 'M' or 'Y'.

For example, if the value of Payable = 'M', then I would calculate the PremiumPayable as YearlyPremium / 12;

```
if (Payable = "M")
{    
    PremiumPayable = YearlyPremium / 12;
}
```

This new value after the calculation will be populated into the PremiumPayable column in the same ListView (different window form).

The Payable and PremiumPayable columns are located in my current Sales ListView, however, the YearlyPremium column is located elsewhere in my Products ListView.

My ListViews have been pre-populated through a connection to a SQL database.

How can I reach and use that Payable value to conduct an if-statement calculation, then pass the result into a new ListView column?

Comment: Honestly, this is the point in programming where you realise doing everything in a business logic tier and binding ListViews to the business objects is the best way to go AND since it has no GUI its testable too! You dont need to test the GUI when its got binding, you only need to test the business logic. I think you'll start seeing what I mean when you clutter your user control stuff with SQL results. You want to use Data Transformation Objects (DTOs) or even better Entity Framework so the SQL schema always matches your code base and the "logic/controllers" is separated from the "View".

Comment: Unfortunately, the task requires me to separate my classes into a Business Logic Layer, Data Connection Layer and Presentation Layer to test function through organisation. My Business Logic Layer only holds the variables declared within the program, and the Presentation Layer includes the UI design and function code used to populate all my ListViews and perform further calculations.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?